Asserting availability of SubTypes of T
I would like to assert whether every element of an array is a sub type of a particular class. So I wrote a helper like this:
    private <T> void assertContainsAllSubtypes(
            List<? extends T> list,
            Class<? extends T>... expectedSubtypes) {
        Set<Class<? extends T>> subtypeSet = 
            new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(expectedSubtypes));

        assertThat(list)
                .isNotEmpty()
                .hasSize(subtypeSet.size())
                .extracting(T::getClass)
                .containsExactlyInAnyOrderElementsOf(subtypeSet);   <-- ERROR
    }

But I get the following error:
Required type:

Iterable
<? extends Class<capture of ? extends T>>

Provided:

Set
<Class<? extends T>>

What am I missing?
Thanks.

i think it might be easier to skip the getClass() call and use hasOnlyElementsOfTypes() instead.  i believe the problem with your current version is that using Object::getClass loses any type information from your generic parameters.

Doesn't help:
Required type:
Iterable
<? extends capture of ? extends T>
Provided:
Set
<Class<? extends T>>


.hasSize(subtypeSet.size()) looks suspicious.  I don't think it's related to the error, but because subtypeSet is a Set, it does mean that your assertion can be satisfied only by Lists whose elements are all of different classes from each other.

Additionally, I think the hasSize() assertion is redundant with the containsExactlyInAnyOrderElementsOf() assertion, which is stronger.  And the isNotEmpty() seems redundant too, except inasmuch as isNotEmpty() makes it impossible for an empty list to satisfy the assertion even in the event that zero expectedSubtypes are provided.

That doesn't seem to be consistent with the diagnostic, @jtahlborn.  Note that the expected type is Iterable<? extends Class<capture of ? extends T>>.  If the issue were getClass() losing type information (which it does), then I would expect the expected type to be Iterable<? extends Class<?>>.

With that said, type information is indeed lost, and it might serve the purpose to intentionally discard it: Set<Class<?>> subtypeSet, or perhaps Set<? extends Class<?>> subtypeSet.

Also, why T::getClass instead of Object::getClass?  You don't need to preserve the T here, because in practice, any Class object is acceptable.  Indeed, I don't follow why the method needs to be generic at all, but surely any point to that is satisfied by type checking at the point of invocation.

I believe this will compile:
  private <T, U extends T> void assertContainsAllSubtypes(
      List<T> list,
      Class<U>... expectedSubtypes) {
    Set<Class<U>> subtypeSet =
        new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(expectedSubtypes));

    assertThat(list)
        .isNotEmpty()
        .hasSize(subtypeSet.size())
        .extracting(T::getClass)
        .containsExactlyInAnyOrderElementsOf(subtypeSet);
  }

Although i still think it's simpler to just do this:
  private <T, U extends T> void assertContainsAllSubtypes(
      List<T> list,
      Class<U>... expectedSubtypes) {

    assertThat(list)
        .isNotEmpty()
        .hasOnlyElementsOfTypes(expectedSubtypes);
  }

(TIL that you can do T::getClass for a generic type)

This might compile, but it probably requires all elements of expectedSubtypes to be the same (U) whereas the author's original intention was to pass different classes as parameters.

@MikeNakis if you look closely at the generic params, the passed in List is type T, so necessarily all the given classes would be sub-types of T.  you can pass in different sub-types of T, and U will just resolve to T.

The helper method that you are (unsuccessfully) trying to compile does not do what you intend it to do, which is "to assert [that] every element of [a list] is a [sub-type] of a particular class."
As user jtahlborn has already shown, you could use the hasOnlyElementsOfTypes() method to replace most of what your method does (or tries to do.)
The only thing remaining is the isNotEmpty() call, but if you think about it for a moment, it is rather unwarranted: an empty list satisfies the condition that it consists only of elements that are sub-types of a particular class. Therefore, your method should not contain a call to isNotEmpty(), and if you want to assert that a list is non-empty, you should assert that separately, on a case by case basis.
Therefore, the best approach is to abandon your plan to write an assertContainsAllSubtypes() method, and in each place where you were planning to invoke that method, explicitly code the following verbose statement instead:
assertThat( myList )
    .isNotEmpty()
    .hasOnlyElementsOfTypes( type1, type2, type3 );

